# 'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor

I am able to run my protractor from a batch file (protractor conf.js) and the script is working fine
I have installed my protractor globally and done environment settings too.
But when I am running my batch file from eclipse after doing settings from external tool configuration .its giving error "'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
My conf.js

```
      exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

My spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });
});
```

My runner.bat

```
protractor conf.js
```

[image: Eclipse settings to run batch file]

Comment: Please show your setting for protractor in Eclipse. Includes the run configuration for protractor if you have.

Comment: Please show the batch file, If you execute the batch file by java code, please also show the java code.

Comment: i have added  the files

Comment: Please show the 'Environment' Tab in above screenshot. And double confirm you can run `protractor --version` in any folder in cmd window by open a cmd window through press `Win+R` keys, and execute `protractor --version` to see you can get the version.  If so, execute `echo %PATH%` and update this cmd output in your question. And screenshot and show the folder where global protractor installed.

Comment: I can run pass with similar setting in eclipse run configuration as in your screenshot and without any setting in `Environment` Tab.  If you double confirm your protractor in `PATH`, you can try add a PATH in `Environment` Tab in run configuration and point it to your protractor global install folder.

Comment: yes..protactor is installed globally. i am able to get protractor version

Comment: ok.in environment path in eclipse i  added this path "C:\Users\surya\AppData\Roaming\npm" and it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double confirmed the global protractor install folder had in `PATH` environment, and it still can't work. Please try to add a `PATH` in `Environment` Tab of Eclipse run configuration, and point the `PATH` to global protractor install folder as following:

[image]